# HTTP POST 403 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, api, http, post

The function "myFunction" makes a call on a authentication API, which returns a token. Im taking the token into the variable "token"  and setting it as header in my next request (in the "deploy" function), but im only getting 403 unauthorized. I tried to make the same call with the same token in Postman, which worked perfectly. Am i doing something wrong with the token here?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>API TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Authenticate</button>
<button onclick="deploy()">Deploy</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    var token = "";
    function myFunction() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            alert(this.status);
            alert(this.readyState);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                token = json["token"];

            }

        };
        xhr.open("POST", "url");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"username": "mariero\\nabilo", "password": "test"}));
    }
    function deploy() {
        alert(token);
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            alert(this.status);
            alert(this.readyState);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "url");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Authorization", token);
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "taskRelativePath":"My Tasks\\Siebel_RBT-1_Prod_IE.atmx",
            "botRunners":
                [{
                    "client":"D00460.lyse.no",
                    "user":"mariero\\RBT-LYD-1"

                }]



        }));
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the alert in `deploy`?

Comment: in the alert(token) i see the token. The readystate is 4 and the status is 0 @LucaKiebel

Comment: The status is 0? Are you using file protocol?

Comment: @LucaKiebel no file protocol

Comment: Quick [debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) tip: use `console.log()` and other console commands to debug, or read about breakpoints [(for example in chrome)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints).

Comment: Thank you @Barthy, but i still can't find the issue here.

Comment: Is `"url"` a string for demonstration purposes?

Comment: @TomaszBubała yes.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({"username": "mariero\\nabilo", "password": "test"})` - I think that the problem lies in this line. Make sure you can authenticate with this credentials